# Reverse for 'posts-details-page' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['all_posts/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I have build the basic Django project but getting error while trying to retrive all the post from the project. you can download the code from github to create the issue, Please guide me how to resolve this issue if anyone can help. **https://github.com/techiekamran/BlogProject.git** and branch name is **starting-blog-project**

```
urls.py
from django.urls import path
from blogapp import views
urlpatterns = [
     path("",views.starting_page,name='starting-page'),
     path("posts",views.posts,name="posts-page"),
     path("all_posts/<slug:slug>",views.post_details,name='posts-details-page'),
     #posts/my-first-post
]

views.py

from datetime import date
from django.shortcuts import render

def get_date(all_posts):
    return all_posts['date']

def starting_page(request):
    sorted_post = sorted(all_posts,key=get_date)
    latest_post = sorted_post[-3:]
    return render(request,'blogapp/index.html',{'posts':latest_post})

def posts(request):
    return render(request,'blogapp/all-posts.html',{'all_posts':all_posts})
    

def post_details(request,slug):
    identified_post=next(post for post in all_posts if post['slug']==slug)
    return render(request,'blogapp/post-details.html',{'post':identified_post})

index.html

{% extends "_base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}
Home
{% endblock %}

{% block css_files %} 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blogapp/post.css' %}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blogapp/index.css' %}"/>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<section id="welcome">
    <header>
        <img src="{% static 'blogapp/images/max.png' %}" alt="Max= The author of this Blog"/>
        <h2>Demo blog des</h2>
    </header>
    <p>Hi, this is the our first blog</p>
</section>

<section id="latest-posts">
    <h2>My latest thoughts</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for post in posts %}
          {% include 'blogapp/includes/post.html' %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

</section>

<section id="about">
    <h2>What I do </h2>
    <p>I love programming</p>
    <p>My goal is to keep</p>
</section>

{% endblock %}
    
post-details.html

{% extends "_base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}
{{ post.title }}
<!--This Post Details-->
{% endblock %}

{% block css_files %} 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "blogapp/post-details.css" %}"/>
{% endblock %}




{% block content %}
<section id="summary">
    {{ post.title }}
    <!--<h2>Post Title</h2>-->
    <article>
        <img src="{% static 'blogapp/images/mountains.jpg' %}" alt="Post Title"/>
        
        <address>By Demo</address>
        <div>
            Last updated on <time>Oct 20</time>
        </div>
    </article>
</section>

<main>
    {{ post.content }}
    <!--<p>this is dumy data</p>
    <p>this is dumy data</p>
    <p>this is dumy data</p>
    <p>this is dumy data</p>
-->
</main>
{% endblock %}


all-posts.html

{% extends "_base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}
All my posts
{% endblock %}

{% block css_files %} 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "blogapp/post.css" %}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blogapp/all-post.css' %}"/>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<section id="all-posts">
    <h2>My collected posts</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for post in all_post %}
        {% include 'blogapp/includes/post.html' %}
        {% endfor %}
        <!-- 
        {% include 'blogapp/includes/post.html' %}
        {% include 'blogapp/includes/post.html' %}
        {% include 'blogapp/includes/post.html' %}
        {% include 'blogapp/includes/post.html' %}
        {% include 'blogapp/includes/post.html' %}
        {% include 'blogapp/includes/post.html' %}
        -->
    </ul>
</section>
{% endblock %}

post.html

{% load static %}

<li>
    
    <article class="post">
  <a href="{% url 'posts-details-page' post.slug %}">Link</a>
        <a href="{% url 'posts-details-page' post.slug %}">
        <img src="{% static 'blogapp/images/'|add:post.image %}" alt="Mountain Hiking" />
       <!--<img src="{% static 'blogapp/images/mountains.jpg' %}" alt="Mountain Hiking" />-->
        <div class="post__content">
            {{ post.slug }}
            <h3>{{ post.title }}
            <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
            
            <!--
                <h3>Mountain hiking</h3>
                <p>There is nothing hike</p>
            -->
            
            
        </div>
        </a>
    </article>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with double quotes in your *all-posts.html* template. If you use outer double quotes, inner ones should be singular. Try change

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "blogapp/post.css" %}"/>
```

To

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blogapp/post.css' %}"/>
```

Comment: Hi Vlad,
I tried to change but still same error

Error during template rendering
BlogProject\blogapp\templates\blogapp\includes\post.html, error at line 6

Reverse for 'posts-details-page' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['all_posts/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']
1 {% load static %}
2 
3 <li>
4     
5     <article class="post">
6   <a href="{% url 'posts-details-page' post.slug %}">Link</a>
Error is in 6th line

Comment: Ok, I think there is an issue with a way you adding a  slug, try:
`<a href="{% url 'posts-details-page' slug=post.slug %}">Link</a>`